# electron window - alwaysontop but not above other apps

Tags: electron

electron `setAlwaysOnTop`  always put the window above ALL apps, how can i make a window that is only always on top, relative to the other electron app windows

Answer (score 1):

found a solution using parents:

```
let top = new BrowserWindow()
let child = new BrowserWindow({ parent: top })
```